# Select2 dropdown menu with overlay effect after click

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

I want to customize a dropdown menu created using "Select2" library.

I'm trying to create overlay effect when menu is open but I'm failing.

Is there anyone who could help me?

Thanks

I want to obtain a dropdown placed at the center of viewport after clicking and a "overlay effect" in background when menu is open.
So, all screen became slightly dark and user can focus only on the dropdown menu.

After click on option, overlay effect in background and dropdown menu disappear.
After click outside of dropdown menu, overlay effect and dropdown menu disappear

Below is code I wrote:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my-select').select2({ 
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.select2-selection {
    background-color: aqua !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.select2-dropdown {
    background-color: red !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>

      <link ref="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js">
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="box">
          <select id="my-select" style="width: 200px">
              <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </div>


      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script type='text/javascript' rc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>

      <!-- Select2 CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <!-- Select2 JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js">
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select2:open` and `select2:close` to trigger the events of select opening and closing then apply the class `ovelay` on your `select2` container here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my-select').select2({});
  
  $('#my-select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $('#container').addClass("overlay");
  });
  
  $('#my-select').on('select2:close', function (e) {
    $('#container').removeClass("overlay");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>

      <link ref="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js">
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container" id="container">
          <div class="box">
              <select id="my-select" style="width: 200px">
                  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>


      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script type='text/javascript' rc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>

      <!-- Select2 CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <!-- Select2 JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js">
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Other solution based on your comment:**

This example adds an overlay element that covers the entire page and sets its `z-index` to 1. It also sets the `z-index` of the `select2-container` element to 2 to make sure it is always on top of the overlay.

When the dropdown is opened, the `select2:open` event is triggered, and the overlay is shown. When the dropdown is closed, the `select2:close` event is triggered, and the overlay is hidden:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-select').select2();

    $('#my-select').on('select2:open', function(e) {
        $('.overlay').show();
    });

    $('#my-select').on('select2:close', function(e) {
        $('.overlay').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

.select2-container {
    z-index: 2;
}

.box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Select2 Example</title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Select2 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Select2 JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <div class="box">
        <select id="my-select" style="width: 200px;">
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Overlay effect sould be over all element of viewport, also over the box class element.

In this way, user focus is only on dropdown menu.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe overlay class has to be added in a different level ?

Comment: I edited my response and added another solution based on your comment, please check and tell me if that what you want

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#my-select').select2({
        
        
        });
    
        $('#my-select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
            $('#container').addClass("overlay");
            $('#box').css('opacity', '0');
        });
          
        $('#my-select').on('select2:close', function (e) {
            $('#container').removeClass("overlay");
            $('#box').css('opacity', '1');
        });
    });
</script>
```